# SWI Prolog. Логическая задача. Талисманы месяцев.

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

По древнему поверью, у каждого месяца есть свой камень-талисман. Так, июню, июлю и сентябрю соответствуют  камни рубин, сапфир и жемчуг. Эти камни означают мудрость, здоровье и благополучие. У какого месяца какой камень-талисман и что он означает, если известно, что:
–   жемчуг и рубин не соответствуют сентябрю;
–   в июне и июле мудрости не наблюдается;
–   здоровье не соответствует рубину;
–   благополучие не относится к июню.
Ну вроде бы код(извиняюсь за говнотранслит атомов) должен выглядеть так:

```
stone(rubin).
stone(sapfir).
stone(jemchug).

meaning(mudrost).
meaning(zdorovie).
meaning(blagopoluchie).

month_stone(september, Y):- not(Y= jemchug), not(Y=rubin).
month_meaning(june, Z):- not(Z=mudrost), not(Z=blagopoluchie).
month_meaning(july, Z):- not(Z=mudrost).
stone_meaning(Y, Z):- Y=rubin, not(Z=zdorovie).
dif(Y1,Y2,Y3):- Y1\=Y2, Y1\=Y3, Y2\=Y3.

rezult(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3):-
X1=june, X2=july, X3=september,
stone(Y1), stone(Y2), stone(Y3),
meaning(Z1), meaning(Z2), meaning(Z3),
stone_meaning(Y1, Z1), stone_meaning(Y2, Z2),
month_stone(X3,Y3),
month_meaning(X1,Z1), month_meaning(X2,Z2),
dif(Y1,Y2,Y3), dif(Z1,Z2,Z3).
```

Но он возвращает false...

Comment: Почему ты три раза написал stone. Почему)

Вроде бы код должен выглядеть так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stone(rubin).
stone(sapfir).
stone(jemchug).

meaning(mudrost).
meaning(zdorovie).
meaning(blagopoluchie).
month_stone(X,_):-not(X=september).
month_stone(september, Y):-not(Y=jemchug),not(Y=rubin).

month_meaning(september,_).
month_meaning(june, Z):- not(Z=mudrost), not(Z=blagopoluchie).
month_meaning(july, Z):- not(Z=mudrost).

stone_meaning(X,_):-not(X=rubin).
stone_meaning(rubin, Z):- not(Z=zdorovie).

rez(X,Y,Z):-   stone(Y),meaning(Z),month_stone(X,Y),month_meaning(X,Z),stone_meaning(Y,Z).

output(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3):-  X1=june,rez(X1,Y1,Z1),X2=september,rez(X2,Y2,Z2),X3=july,rez(X3,Y3,Z3),Y1\=Y2,Y1\=Y3,Z1\=Z2,Z1\=Z3.
```

Comment: 100 ?- output(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3).
X1 = june,
Y1 = jemchug,
Z1 = zdorovie,
X2 = september,
Y2 = sapfir,
Z2 = mudrost,
X3 = july,
Y3 = rubin,
Z3 = blagopoluchie 

Результаты.

Comment: спасибо огромное, понял в чём косяк :)

Comment: Да не за что:-) В чем? Три раза не надо писать было stone meaning. Проставь ответ как верный тогда.